# When "some of the" should absolutely be replaced with just "some"?

Tags: difference, definite-article

I've read ["some " vs. "some of "](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/64557) and [“Some” vs “some of” with adjective](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/102716) but I'm still having trouble figuring out in which cases `"some of the"` should always be replaced with just `"some"`.

I've encountered this problem when trying to apply fixes from LanguageTool to texts from a game. Including examples with most of the context there is prior to "some of the":

> A towering coniferous tree that belongs to the 'Pinus' genus, with the New England species varying from 'P. strobus', 'P. resinosa' and 'P. rigida'.  **Some of the** branches have been stripped away...

> This wattle-and-daub wall has **some of the** wooden strip lattice in place...

> This binder details the scheduled maintenance for several plumbing systems throughout the facility.  However, **some of the** log sheets seem to be filled with

> This massive antique book documents dances from all around the world in great detail.  A perceptive reader could learn a lot about defensive footwork from **some of the** war dances.

> This hefty binder contains a multitude of diagrams and technical specifications for various electronic materials.  **Some of the** diagrams use symbols you've not seen before

> This textbook details the military history of ancient China, with a particular focus on the nature of historical arms and armor.  It also details **some of the** equipment used by other cultures

> You were an avid fencer, starting with foil and moving onto saber, then épée.  You competed nationally and dabbled with **some of the** historical fencing weapons

> I've talked to **some of the** traders who have been there

> **Some of the** others in the shelter got stung

There are much more [where these came from](https://github.com/CleverRaven/Cataclysm-DDA/pull/42585/files) and I'm not looking for solutions just to these ones but for a rule of thumb to quickly decide whether the change is absolutely required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all your examples, *the* refers to a particular group of people or things, of which *some* are mentioned specially.

Some of *the branches of a particular tree* (at least, I assume that's what it refers to).

Some of *the wooden strip lattice which would originally have been part of the wall.*

Some of *the log sheets in the binder* - and so on.

There is no reason to change any of these to just *some.*

Comment: Well, I've found one instance where it seems appropriate: `"Some of the bridges, they're right next to each other, right?"` because it is the start of a hint and it means just any bridges in the game.

Comment: OK, but "Some of the branches of a particular tree" can mean two things: 1 Some of all the branches of a tree 2 Some of the branches (mentioned before) of a tree. In essence, we get 1 Some of all the branches 2 some of some of the branches